# How to lock content on Facebook open graph

Tags: facebook

How to lock content on Facebook open graph, i want that a user likes the Facebook page and till that time the lock content should not be shown and as soon the user likes the page it will automatically be shared on his profile. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Facebook does not allow Like Gating any more. You need to make the same content available to all visitors, no matter if they liked your page or not. // Before you make any more plans about this kind of "blackmail marketing", you should go read https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: but mostly on the sites there is an option coming to unlock it and that work too

Comment: It doesn't matter what you see on other sites - it is simply not allowed by Facebook.

Comment: Then please message me the sites that does it and I will forward those internally to Developer Operations and they will take care of it